# How to remove the delete option of ng-select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

`<ng-select  [items]=items  [(ngModel)]=mySelect  [multiple]="true"> </ng-select>`
I need to set particular advantage that make ng-select read/write only, there no delete actions

Answer (score 0):

**ng-select** is an npm package and open source project as well. If you use it as a package then you are limited with the provided options. If it does not provide this option, you can visit their [GitHub](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) page and create an issue